# SUM column values based off differing results of separate column

Tags: sql, h2

Consider a relation that contained the names and number of locations of restaurants including split and stand alone restaurants:

```
RESTAURANT:          NUM_OF_LOC
Pizza Hut            1
Pizza Hut/Taco Bell  2
Taco Bell            2
```

Also consider you will not know the name of the restaurant, stand alone or split, or Number of Locations. The only consistent piece is the "/" string character between split restaurants.

How to return the above table as a result with the number of stand alone restaurants summed into the number of split restaurants in desc, like so:

```
RESTAURANT:             NUM_OF_LOC
Pizza Hut/Taco Bell     5
Taco Bell               2
Pizza Hut               1
```

Answer (score 0):

So are you looking to get the count of all restaurants for just Taco Bell and Pizza Hut where a joint counts as 1 for each or are you looking to count all occurrences of each variant?

I'm thinking you aren't just looking for totals and are looking to tear apart the combined restaurants so you can do something like

```
SELECT name, count(*)
FROM restaurants 
WHERE CONTAINS (name, 'Taco Bell')
```

Relooking it seems like you want the consolidated groups to include all occurrences of either which would be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE sums AS 
SELECT name, count(*) 
FROM restaurants 
WHERE CONTAINS (name, 'Taco Bell') 
OR CONTAINS(name, 'Pizza Hut')
```